# : Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, db2

i create a spring boot sample from spring.io and i add this dependency :
web,jpa,driver db2,but i have this error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]:
>   Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   sun/io/ByteToCharConverter
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$137/770947228.getObject(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at com.example.springboot.SpringbootApplication.main(SpringbootApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na]
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]:
>   Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   sun/io/ByteToCharConverter
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         ... 20 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/ByteToCharConverter
>         at hit.db2sql.k.(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.j.b(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.j.c(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.ab.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.ac.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.ac.o(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.ac.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.ac.n(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.y.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.c.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.c.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.c.a(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.c.(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2.Db2Driver.newConnection(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at hit.db2sql.b.connect(DashoA8514) ~[hitjdbcdb2.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$Lambda$461/2090563811.get(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$$Lambda$462/704869156.get(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:133)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>         ... 21 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.io.ByteToCharConverter
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
>         ... 63 common frames omitted

My entity class

```
package com.example.springboot.model;
//import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Table(name = "employee")
@Entity(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "bs",sequenceName = "bike_seq",allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "bs")
    private long empid;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(20)")
    private String empname;

    public long getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }

    public void setEmpid(long empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }

    public String getEmpname() {
        return empname;
    }

    public void setEmpname(String empname) {
        this.empname = empname;
    }
}
```

Component

```
package com.example.springboot.control;
import com.example.springboot.model.Employee;
import com.example.springboot.repos.EmpRep;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/s")
public class EmpCont {

    @Autowired
    private EmpRep empRep;

    @GetMapping("/a")
    public List<Employee> bikes()
    {
        return empRep.findAll();
    }

}
repository
package com.example.springboot.repos;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface EmpRep extends JpaRepository {
}
```

application.property

```
spring.jackson.serialization.INDENT_OUTPUT=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=pervasive
spring.datasource.username=11
spring.datasource.password=11
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=hit.db2.Db2Driver
spring.messages.basename=messages
server.servlet.context-path=/pervasive
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect



pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>hit.db2.db2Driver</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>hitjdbcdb2</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>8.1</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hit.db2.db2Driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>hitlicense</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hit.db2.db2Driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>hitjdbcdb2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.3.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>6.0.16.Final</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: sun.io.ByteToCharConverter is deprecated and removed from JRE 1.8 and higher.   Check your *versions* of each level of the stack...

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide the hibernate entity (Employee.class) and data type of the primary key (Long) to the spring data jpa repository. The correct implementation would be

```
@Repository
public interface EmpRep extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```